# C++: gcc can't find static member when linking

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

I get the error:

```
file.cpp:20: undefined reference to `MyClass::arr'
```

At this line, I have:

```
#include "MyClass.hpp"
extern "C" {
void MyClass::func() {
 arr = 0;
}
```

At header:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
     static int arr;
     static void func();
}
```

P.S. gcc (4.x) is called with: `-Xlinker -zmuldefs` to avoid multiple definition checking.

Comment: Why `#include <MyClass.hpp>` instead of `#include "MyClass.hpp"`? Usually `<>s` indicate library includes.

Comment: Argh, my bad. cleaned up the example.

Comment: @David: It's possible for `extern "C"` to change calling convention as well (for example, if you have the default set to `__stdcall` on MSVC++, `extern "C"` will make sure things are using `__cdecl` instead)

Comment: @Billy: I realized that just after writing the comment, so I deleted the comment before seeing yours. You are right, in that it does have an effect in the calling convention. The next thing to check for me would be whether it is admissible (my gut feeling is that it is not) to declare it without `extern "C"` and define it with it --the calling convention would not be accessible to translation units that only saw the declaration, and code there would try to call the function with the wrong convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This makes no sense :

```
#include <MyClass.hpp>
extern "C" {
void MyClass::func() {
 arr = 0;
}
```

write

```
#include <MyClass.hpp>

int MyClass::arr = 0; // needs to be instantiated to satisfy linker.

void MyClass::func() 
{
  arr = 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 -- but the `extern "C"` is probably required to use `func` as a pthreads callback function.

Comment: @Billy How is compiler supposed to make MyClass::func extern "C" if such a thing does not exist in C?

Comment: @Tomek: I my albeit limited understanding, it can't. In order to strictly speaking be portable, your thread function cannot be a member function. It doesn't matter on a lot of platforms though because the extern "C" calling convention matches the static calling convention on those machines.

Answer (score 1):

implementation

```
#include "MyClass.hpp"

 void MyClass::func()
 {
     this->arr = 0;
 }
```

header file

```
class MyClass 
{
public:
    static int arr;
    static void func();
}
```

Comment: You need `extern "C"` in there to make the call from pthreads.

Answer (score 1):

Static class fields, after being *declared* in the `class` statement, must be also defined in a single `.cpp` file. In such file you should put:

```
int MyClass::arr;
```

By the way, the `#include` statements have `<>` brackets only when you're including system headers; for your own headers you should use the usual double quotes (`""`).